# AtCoder Beginner Contest 070 C問題が通らなくなる

Tags: python, python3

## 説明

https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc070/tasks/abc070_c
私はこの問題を解答したのですが、ACを貰う過程で原因不明のエラーに遭遇しました。
自力ではREが出た原因を究明できなかったので、ここで質問させて頂きました。

### 自分の解答

```py
from fractions import gcd

def lcm(a, b):
    return (a * b) // gcd(a, b)

n = int(input())

ans = 1
for i in range(n):
    t = int(input())
    ans = lcm(t, ans)
print(ans)
```

## 原因不明のエラー

### intによるキャストと//による切り捨て除算の違い

ここで関数`lcm`の
`return (a * b) // gcd(a, b)`
を
`return int(a * b) / gcd(a, b)`

に変更するとエラーが発生します。
この変更によってなぜエラーが発生するのでしょうか？

### fractionsとmathによるgcdの違い

上の自分の解答の部分の
`from fractions import gcd`
を
`from math import gcd`
に変更するとエラーが発生してしまいます。
両者同じgcdという機能を持つにもかかわらず、なぜエラーが起こるのでしょうか？

Comment: 最初のはこちらの記事 [この２つのコードのどこが異なるのか教えて下さい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61899/26370) と類似でしょうか。2つ目はこちらの記事 [\[Python\] AtCoderで使えるPythonのversionは3.4.3](https://qiita.com/k_yamashita/items/1c8216ddb0b56fbdac46) の関連かもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**kunif**さんのコメントにより、この問題が解決されました。

## intによるキャストと//による切り捨て除算の違い

[この２つのコードのどこが異なるのか教えて下さい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61899/%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae%ef%bc%92%e3%81%a4%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a9%e3%81%93%e3%81%8c%e7%95%b0%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

両者の計算方法の精度による違いが原因でした。

## fractionsとmathによるgcdの違い

https://qiita.com/k_yamashita/items/1c8216ddb0b56fbdac46

atcoder上とローカル環境でのpythonのバージョンの違いが原因でした。